# EJB lookup failed in GlassFish 4.1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I try to lookup for a local EJB with jndi,  and it failed

The save method of `EssaiImpl` EJB is called by a request scoped managed bean.

The local interface is:

```
@Local
public interface Essai {
    public void save();
}
```

and the implementation is:

```
@Stateless
public class EssaiImpl implements Essai {

    /**
     * Tag des logs
     */
    static private Class<EssaiImpl> logTag = EssaiImpl.class;

    public EssaiImpl() {}

    public void save() {
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            Essai business = (Essai) context.lookup("java:module/EssaiImpl");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.erreur(logTag, "Exception :" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

(Logger is just a simple logging encapsulation)

I always have the exception:

```
[#|2016-01-01T13:16:00.628+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1||_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-8;_TimeMillis=1451650560628;_LevelValue=800;|
  Caller+1       at com.test.EssaiImpl.save(EssaiImpl.java:33)
 - Exception :com.sun.proxy.$Proxy220 cannot be cast to com.test.EssaiImpl|#]
```

Any help would be helpful,

Comment: I am not sure to understand stackoverflow process, but it seems that my question has been rejected by a robot, is it the case ?

Comment: A message inbox suggested that the question has been rejected, but if it is not the case : no problem.

Comment: I really need the answer, i do not see why the code does not run, i try with jboss as to see if this is a poroblem with Glassfish.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you suggested, It would be safer to use Glassfish 4.0 or a 3.X ?

Comment: I just tried with wildfy 9.0.2 and it runs without trouble ...

Comment: so i guess that i have to use another server than Glassfish 4.1.1 ...

Comment: Your code seems to work on fresh Glassfish installation. The exception might be due to classpath issues, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973983/java-ee-proxy-cannot-be-cast-to-local-interface-maybe-classloading-issue). Is your code packaged in single WAR / EAR? Can you retry with a new glassfish installation?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on GF-4.1, 4.1.1 and 4.1.1 web-profile.
Created a project with 3 classes and 1 interface:
RestConfigure:

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
public class RestConfigure extends Application {}
```

EssaiResource:

```
@Path("/call")
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class EssaiResource {
    @Inject Essai essai;
    @GET public String callEssai() {
       essai.save();
       return "called essai";
    }
}
```

And your Essai interface:

```
@Local
public interface Essai {
    void save();
}
```

And EssaiImpl:

```
@Stateless
public class EssaiImpl implements Essai {
    public void save() {
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            Essai business = (Essai) context.lookup("java:module/EssaiImpl");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Just changed the logger to `ex.printStacktrace()` for now.

Hope this might help you...

Ivar

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Always lookup the interface**.

*Wrong:*

```
Essai business = (Essai) context.lookup("java:module/EssaiImpl");
```

**Correct:**

```
Essai business = (Essai) context.lookup("java:module/Essai");
```