# Using same classloader for ear and war

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, classloader, war

Currently we have more than 100 wars/ejbs bundled in an ear.
Because we dont want to deploy all of them always we would like to split 
the deployment in:

- ejb-ear

  - ejb1.jar
  - entities.jar
- first.war
- second.war
- third.war

How is it possible to simply lookup the ejb1.jar from one of the deployed wars - if it is possible.

I read following document but I can`t figure out how to get this working.

I can do a lookup on the ejb in the ear but I cant cast it to an Interface. Which seems to be right because this are different class loaders.

See: 
[Java EE: Proxy cannot be cast to Local Interface, maybe classloading issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973983/java-ee-proxy-cannot-be-cast-to-local-interface-maybe-classloading-issue)

Comment: What application server do you use?

Comment: @mentallurg We would like to use wildfly > 10

Comment: 1) Your WARs are not inside EAR and you want to deploy each WAR independently on EAR? So that you have 100+ applications. Right? 2( In each WAR you want to use EJBs whose implementations is packaged inside EAR. Correct?

Comment: 1) Our WARs are not inside the ear, they should be deployed independently.
We have a lot of WARs. (about 100)
2) Yes, some WARs need to Inject some Beans which are inside the EAR

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a Remote Interface which leads to marshalling and unmarshalling (performance) or you introduce a module dependency from the WARs to the EAR by adding deployment.MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME e.g. to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Then you use the same classloader, but your WARs might go offline while you redeploy the EAR.

See e.g. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/development_guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules#Dynamic_Module_Naming1

for documentation.

Comment: I created a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` which looks like:
`<jboss-deployment-structure> <deployment>  <dependencies>    <module name="deployment.ejb-ear.ear"/>  </dependencies> </deployment> </jboss-deployment-structure>` but it is not possible to load the ejbs inside the ear.

Edit: I tried to inject the beans from the ear with :  `@Inject
  private Instance<TestingInterface> instances;`

Answer (score 0):

There can be different solutions.

1) Package into the EAR those WARs only that use EJBs. Then you can use EJBs via local interfaces. All other WARs can still be deployed independently, and they *don't need* the same class loader as EAR.

2) Use remote EJBs. Package into WARs the interfaces of EJBs that they use. Again, no need in the same class loader. And if you are worried about performance of remote EJBs, then first test the real püerformance. Jboss developers have optimized performance a lot. For instance, [read here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project?_sscc=t), they optimized EJB calls

> ... to avoid doing unnecessary server side communication(s) which
>   would typically involve network calls, marshalling/unmarshalling etc.

3) Analyze dependencies of WARs and EJBs, also dependencies between EJBs on each other. Try to identify 4-5 groups or "clusters" of EJBs and WARs that are very close to each other and that use only a few EJBs from other groups, or even use no EJBs from other groups. Then package such groups into separate EARs. For instance, you can have:

- A main EAR that provides 20 EJBs responsible for user and permission management
- One EAR with 10 EJBs and 5 WARs for product management
- One EAR with 20 EJBs and 30 WARs for order management
- One EAR with ... EJBs and ... WARs for shipment management

Then in the most cases you will deploy only one of these EARs and thus your deployment times will be 4-5 times faster.

Comment: The Problem ist, that there are some ejbs used by all WARs. Currently we have one (very) big EAR and we would like to split it into one smaller EAR and WARs.
   
We thought about idea 2) but then we need to bundle all the Entities the EJBs (Interfaces) need. That would be a massiv overload if every >100Wars bundles the same entities, isn't it?

Comment: Normally interfaces change seldom. If an EJB changes, mainly changes its implementation, e.g. there is a new requirement and business logic in an EJB changes. So you would often deploy an EAR with EJB implementations. But it will be in the most cases **not needed** to redeploy also the WARs, because **interfaces have not changed**. That's why I don't understand why you are talking about redeployment of WARs.

Comment: I never said anything about redeploying the wars at the same time I redeploy the ejbs.

Comment: OK, then I misinterpreted your question. Then why dobn't you use remote EJBs? As I said above (see variant 2) JBos has optimized performance. So you will not see much difference between local and remote cases, if WARs and EAR are deployed on the same server. Why don't you consider remote EJBs?

Comment: For example, when using a `GlobalEJB` (used in each WAR) we need to bundle all the entities in each WAR. May I understand this wrong but this would mean that every 100 entities will be loaded in each deployment (class loader). This could lead to a bigger classloader and a bigger memoryusage. As it seems it is not possible to use one classloader for all deployments, so I can't put the WAR dependency to the entities to provided. I think I will test solution 3

Comment: What you mean by *to bundle all the entities*? In WAR you include only the remote interface of this EJB. If remote interface uses some bean / DTO classes, of course you add them to WAR, too. But the interfaces need little memory. The *implementation* of EJBs can need more classes, and it can really need more memory *in EAR*, but *not in WAR*. Why are you talking about *bigger memory usage* in WARs? Do you mean that each remote interface will be loaded in each WAR and that's why you *expect* that you will get 100x more memory?

Comment: JRE has more than 4000 classes. So your 100 classes will be relatively small to the rest. I'd suggest that you don't do a *premature optimization*, but measure the real memory usage. Of course in case of 100 separate WARs it will be higher than in case of these WARs packaged to single EAR. But in this case again the solution 3 can help, because you can share classes within each of 4-5 EARs.